# Erlang: Problem with crypo:sha()

Tags: erlang

This works in my erlang shell:

```
1> U = default_user_name().
2> crypto:start().
3> crypto:sha(U).
4> crypto:stop().
```

But when I compile this:

```
default_pw() ->
    U = default_user_name(),
    crypto:start(),
    crypto:sha(U),
    crypto:stop().
```

And execute it in the erlang shell, I get this:

1> person:default_pw().

** exception error: bad argument

```
 in function  port_control/3

    called as port_control(crypto_drv04,5,<<"jDoe">>)

 in call from crypto:control/2
```

Two questions:

1) What am I doing wrong?

2) It seems that I need to start and stop the crypto server. But is there a better place to start and stop it in my application?

Many thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting indicates that the crypto application was not started. An easy way to start it is just to add it as a parameter to `erl` like so:

```
$ erl -s crypto
```

I had a look at the current implementation of crypto and the past release notes for erlang and I came to the following conclusions (someone please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. Erlang releases <14A require crypto to be started prior to calling any functions because the library used a port driver. This makes sense because I got the error you described with 13B04 after not starting crypto.
2. Erlang releases >=14A don't require crypto to be started as the implementation now uses NIFs. This makes sense because the current implementation of crypto_server.erl is just a `gen_server` template, and on 14B03 I don't need to start the application in order to make `crypto:sha/1` work.